# Download only part of a GitHub repository on a TeamCity build server

Tags: git, github, teamcity

So I have a GitHub repository with multiple .NET projects. My TeamCity currently downloads all the code, but then builds only the few projects I need. Is there a way to make it only download part of the repository?

Answer (score 21):

You just need to setup your VCS roots **once**, and don't have to create one per project.

Then, for a given project, you need to edit checkout rules in the administration page.

1. Go to {TEAMCITY_URL}/admin/editBuildTypeVcsRoots.html?id=buildType:bt{PROJECT_ID}
2. Click on the link "edit checkout rules (0)"
3. Add the two following rules:

   ```
   -:.
   +:path/to/your/project/in/github
   ```

This way your project configuration will checkout only the relevant part of your github repository.

You can have more details about the checkout rules in the [Teamcity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/VCS+Checkout+Rules).

Comment: Agent side checkout doesn't support sub-folder checkout for git. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Git+(JetBrains)#Git%28JetBrains%29-Limitations

Comment: It [appears](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Git#Git-Limitations) that as of 10.0 they do support it.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding to what Sébastien Saunier wrote above:
If you want that sub folder in Github to become your root folder of the build folder, than you have to add =>.

For Example:

```
-:.
+:subfolder=>.
```

Hope this helps,
Guy

Comment: Agent side checkout doesn't support sub-folder checkout for git. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Git+(JetBrains)#Git%28JetBrains%29-Limitations

Answer (score -2):

Create a separate repository which contains only those projects that you need to compile and have TC pull from there.

Other than that, no. TC will always pull an entire VCS root.

Comment: Thx Stere, but how do I get GitHub to push the changes from the original repo to the copy?

Comment: I hereby retract my answer in light of Sebastien's. I was seemingly unaware of the checkout rules approach. I scribbled an answer down too quickly without thinking it through and I am thoroughly ashamed of my behaviour. It won't happen again  :-)